# Keras: BiLSTM only works when return_sequences=True

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

I've been trying to implement this BiLSTM in Keras: https://github.com/ffancellu/NegNN

Here is where I'm at, and it kind of works:

```
inputs_w = Input(shape=(sequence_length,), dtype='int32')
inputs_pos = Input(shape=(sequence_length,), dtype='int32')
inputs_cue = Input(shape=(sequence_length,), dtype='int32')

w_emb = Embedding(vocabulary_size+1, embedding_dim, input_length=sequence_length, trainable=False)(inputs_w)
p_emb = Embedding(tag_voc_size+1, embedding_dim, input_length=sequence_length, trainable=False)(inputs_pos)
c_emb = Embedding(2, embedding_dim, input_length=sequence_length, trainable=False)(inputs_cue)

summed = keras.layers.add([w_emb, p_emb, c_emb])

BiLSTM = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(hidden_dims, return_sequences=True))(summed)

DPT = Dropout(0.2)(BiLSTM)

outputs = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(DPT)

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('bilstm_one_hot.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0001, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

model = Model(inputs=[inputs_w, inputs_pos, inputs_cue], outputs=outputs)

model.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit([X_train, X_pos_train, X_cues_train], Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early, checkpoint])
```

In the original code, in Tensorflow, the author uses masking and softmax cross entropy with logits. I don't get how to implement this in Keras yet. If you have any advice don't hesitate.

My main issue here is with return_sequences=True. The author doesn't appear to be using it in his tensorflow implementation and when I turn it to False, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (820, 109, 2)
```

I also tried using:

```
outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))(BiLSTM)
```

which returns and AssertionError without any information.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the author uses masking and softmax cross entropy with logits. I don't get how to implement this in Keras yet.

Regarding softmax cross entropy with logits, you are doing it correctly. `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` as the loss function + no activation function on the last layer is the same as your approach with `categorical_crossentropy` as loss + `softmax` activation on the last layer. The only difference is that the latter one is numerically less stable. If this turns out to be an issue for you, you can (if your Keras backend is tensorflow) just pass `tf.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` as your loss. If you have another backend, you will have to look for an equivalent there.

Regarding masking, I'm not sure if I fully understand what the author is doing. However, in Keras the `Embedding` layer has a `mask_zero` parameter that you can set to `True`. In that case all timesteps that have a `0` will be ignored in all further calculations. In your source, it is not `0` that is being masked, though, so you would have to adjust the indices accordingly. If that doesn't work, there is the `Masking` layer in Keras that you can put before your recurrent layer, but I have little experience with that.

> My main issue here is with return_sequences=True. The author doesn't
>   appear to be using it

What makes you think that he doesn't use it? Just because that keyword does not appear in the code doesn't mean anything. But I'm also not sure. The code is pretty old and I don't find it in the docs anymore that could tell what the defaults are.

Anyway, if you want to use `return_sequences=False` (for whatever reason) be aware that this changes the output shape of the layer:

- with `return_sequences=True` the output shape is `(batch_size, timesteps, features)`
- with `return_sequences=False` the output shape is `(batch_size, features)`

The error you are getting is basically telling you that your network's output has one dimension less than the target `y` values you are feeding it.
So, to me it looks like `return_sequences=True` is just what you need, but without further information it is hard to tell.

Then, regarding [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed). I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with it, but quoting from the docs:

> This wrapper applies a layer to every temporal slice of an input.
>
> **The input should be at least 3D**, and the dimension of index one will be considered to be the temporal dimension.

(emphasis is mine)

I'm not sure from your question, in which scenario the empty assertion occurs.

If you have a recurrent layer with `return_sequences=False` before, you are again missing a dimension (I can't tell you why the assertion is empty, though).

If you have a recurrent layer with `return_sequences=True` before, it should work, but it would be completely useless, as `Dense` is applied in a time distributed way anyways. If I'm not mistaken, this behavior of the `Dense` layer was changed in some older Keras version (they should really update the example there and stop using `Dense`!). As the code you are referring to is quite old, it's well possible that `TimeDistributed` was needed back then, but is not needed anymore.

If your plan was to restore the missing dimension, `TimeDistributed` won't help you, but `RepeatVector` would. But, as already said, in that case better use `return_sequences=True` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations ! You assumed right. The empty assertion occurs when return_sequences=False which is normal.

So apparently, the implementation I have is quite similar to Fancellu's. But the results are significantly lower than what I get with the tensorflow implementation which I updated to tensorflow 1.13. I'll investigate that next.

Comment: what about masking ? in the original code, there is a placeholder which is fed and then used to compute loss:

`self.mask = tf.placeholder("float",name="input_mask")`
...
`_mask = [1 if t!=vocsize - 1 else 0 for t in X]`
...
`_bilstm.mask: _mask`
...
`self.loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels = self.y, logits=outputs),self.mask))/tf.reduce_sum(self.mask)`

Comment: @D.Clem oh sorry, I completely missed the masking part of your question. Will update my answer soon

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was able to replicate the results by initializing embedding with a specific RandomUniform with -1 to 1 scale

`keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0, seed=None)`

Now I'm trying to add an attention layer. But the layer here outputs a 2D tensor with shape: (samples, features) which does not work with my network:

https://www.kaggle.com/takuok/bidirectional-lstm-and-attention-lb-0-043

Comment: @D.Clem shouldn't be too complicated to make it fit your shape. If you are facing a specific problem, I'd suggest you open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your target values seem to be time distributed. So you have 109 timesteps with a onehot target vector of size two. This is why you need the return_sequences=True. Otherwise you will just feed the last timestep to the Dense layer and you would just have one output.

So depending on what you need you need to keep it like it is now or if just the last timestep is enough for you you can get rid of it, but then you would need to adjust the y values accordingly.

Comment: Okay so each word constitute a timestep in this case. 

btw: 820: sentences, 109: words(padding), 2: labels ( each word is either O_scope or I_scope) 

Any idea why these two work the same with return_sequence=True ?

outputs = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(BiLSTM)
outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))(BiLSTM)

Comment: @D.Clem `TimeDisributed` has no effect with `Dense` in newer Keras versions, see my answer